# Change letters from black to white on image

Tags: colors, image-editing, image-processing

I have an image of a logo (format `*.jpg` but can use others if necessary), which has black letters on a white background, like this:

[image]

I would like to change the letters from back to white, while still retaining a black edge/contour for each letter so that you can still see them (otherwise it's just white letters on a white background, which isn't really readable).

Can anybody suggest how to do this? I have looked around but couldn't find any obvious way to do this. I'm open to which software is best suited for the job (preferrably free), but do not have access to Photoshop ($$$).

Comment: This would be better asked over on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @spikey_richie Thanks for the suggestion. Can you or somebody with the relevant privileges move the question across, or shall I delete it and ask it again on the suggested SE?

Comment: Probably quicker to just re-ask the question over there.

Answer (score 2):

Somebody suggested using the [edge detection features in ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/transform/#edge) before their answer was deleted and I managed to make it work.

The following gave me what I wanted:

```
magick convert Logo-positive.jpg -negate -edge 5 -negate Logo-positive-edges.jpg
```

[image]